# Unable to access AD login in iPhone Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I am trying to access `AD Authentication` through an app in Xamarin forms. I am using this code

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(tenantUrl);

if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().FirstOrDefault().Authority);

var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", ApplicationID, new Uri(returnUri), new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController));
```

While using an iPhone I am getting this error [You can't get there from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i57J6.png)